# Captcha Image with Python Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize, captcha

My question is very similiar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627923/how-to-get-generated-captcha-image-using-mechanize)
The difference is that the captcha is generated by server at request-time with some kind of authentication(that must come from a javascript request) or whatever. I know this, because if I follow the src attribute of the captcha image the server gives me a big 404 right on me face.

If I open it with mechanize, it will probably "see" this image(so, it means the server already generated). Since I can't generate the captcha manually, I'll have to seek for this image inside what mechanize gives me.

So, If I could get a binary response of what mechanize is "seeing" I could decode the image and build it with base64(don't know if that's right, I saw a pdf-to-html converter converting an image for a base64 representation), right?

Is there such a way? Or a similar approach?

Thank you VERY much in advance!

Comment: You can try to do the same thing with selenium, it can give you a visual aspect (difference is that selenium handles javascript)

Comment: +1 That will solve, not this one, but a lot of thers(cause turns out, it's not javascript requesting the captcha. Although the real link for the captcha is inside a javascript file, in which cause I don't need to handle). Thank you.